Two PowerDNS servers as Autoprimary for each other
I have set up two PowerDNS servers in different datacenters and am trying to make them highly available. I am using PowerDNS 4.9.1 and DNS-UI as the web interface to simplify zone editing. On both servers I have a web server set up so I can log in to any of the servers and see zones, etc.
The idea was simple: I set them up to be a supermaster (autoprimary) to each other, so if I edit zone records on the first DNS server (via web, actually), then I should see those edits on the second server, and vice versa - that was the idea.
In real life, when I edit zone on server1, those changes are perfectly sent to server2. But when I edit zone on server2, server1 doesn't accept it. Log on server1 says:
Received NOTIFY for _zonenname_ from _server2_ but we are primary (rejected)

So it seems that PowerDNS doesn't work well when both servers are set to autoprimary.
Here are the configs for both servers:
webserver=yes
webserver-address=127.0.0.1
webserver-allow-from=127.0.0.1
webserver-port=8081
api=yes
api-key=***
include-dir=/etc/powerdns/pdns.d
launch=

log-dns-details=yes
log-dns-queries=yes

allow-axfr-ips=server1_ip,server2_ip
disable-axfr=no

primary=yes
secondary=yes
autosecondary=yes

security-poll-suffix=
setgid=pdns
setuid=pdns
daemon=yes
guardian=yes

allow-dnsupdate-from=0.0.0.0/0
dnsupdate=yes
loglevel=5

Actually, I might be wrong in getting the idea of autoprimary/autosecondary. What I need is to have each server trust zone change notification sent by another server in the pair, and AXFR the zone. This way I can edit zone by logging into any of the servers and downtime of any of these servers won't stop zone work.

It's not about the servers being set to "autoprimary"; it's about them being set to "primary" in general, whether auto or not. AXFR is strongly directional, as it originates from systems where you'd edit the zone as a text file on the master server – maybe it's not fundamentally limited to a single direction, but most implementations, PowerDNS included, handle it that way.
More than that, it seems to me that PowerDNS is not really designed for traditional AXFR replication at all – the documentation strongly implies it's a second-tier feature, considering e.g. it being off by default, and the complete lack of support for 'IXFR' incremental replication.
So if you want to have a multi-master setup, then don't AXFR the zone at all. Instead set up a backend database such as OpenLDAP or MariaDB or Postgres – each DNS server hosting its own instance of the DB at 'localhost' – and configure bidirectional replication between instances of that database.
(I believe both OpenLDAP and Postgres support bidirectional replication; not sure whether MariaDB does, but the latter can at least switch directions as needed.)

This.  Set up 2 primary servers and use database replication in the backend, or write something that pushes the zone files and data to both servers.  I've done both these things and they work very well.   (I'm not keen at all on multi-master stuff - it would seem unnecessarily complex and likely to fail - and if your master DNS server is not working, should you really be trying to update the secondary?

@davidgo I've not worked with multi-master in other databases, but it's quite reliable in OpenLDAP, and it's also how Active Directory servers (and therefore also their AD-hosted DNS zones) operate all the time. You do lose update atomicity, I guess, but since this sounds a 1-admin operation it should be fine.
